# Knit to Word is only outputting the first 11 pages of report (which should be 70+)

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown, knitr

I have an R markdown file that knits to HTML and PDF with no problems (except tables being too wide in the PDF). However, when I knit to Word, I get a document that is only 11 pages long. The PDF document is 72 pages in comparison. The word document just cuts off in the middle of a table, the header and 5 lines print and then there just isn't another page.

I've updated my packages and restarted RStudio but I'm at a loss for what else to try, especially since there are no problems knitting to either HTML or PDF. What would cause this? And how do I fix it?

UPDATE: I isolated the area that was causing the issue and then slowing copied sections into a new markdown file until finding the chunk that caused the issue. Ultimately, I removed the `autofit()` function in all of my `flextable()` created tables and that seems to solve the issue. I guess that was only used in the flextables in the first part of the report and set the width more specifically in the later sections. This seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: Maybe there is some kind of character combination in that table that causes the issue. Have you tried removing the table and other elements around the page where the cutoff happens? Does that change anything? If you can identify the offending element put it in a code chunk in your question, maybe that way we can figure out the issue.

Comment: I tried taking out the code chunk that created the table where it cut off and it just cut off in the middle of a different table. However, when I take out that whole section of the report and put it into a new markdown file, it still has issues, so there maybe something to that. I'll try to look carefully at that particular section and see if I can isolate a problem.